# Loop through a string in lisp for alpha chars OR space

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp, space

I'm looking for how to loop through a string in LISP to check for alpha char or spaces. A sentence like "Coffee is Friend" is something that i want to check as Valid. But when i do  (every #'alpha-char-p "coffee is best"') it fails on the spaces because the space is not technically alpha-char. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Simply test for alpha-char *or* space:

```
 (every 
   (lambda (c) (or (alpha-char-p c) (char= c #\Space))) 
   "coffee is best")
```

[`every`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#every) takes as first parameter a function that must return non-nil on every element of the sequence second parameter.

Answer (score 8):

Using `LOOP`:

```
CL-USER > (loop for c across "tea is best"
                always (or (alpha-char-p c)
                           (char= c #\space)))
T
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the complexity of the task, you might as well use regular expressions. If you load [CL-PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/), you can write:

```
(ppcre:scan "^[ a-zA-Z]*$"  "Coffee is Friend")
```

The regular expression that is accepted by the library is a Perl-like string, or a parse-tree. For example, calling `(ppcre:parse-string "^[ a-zA-Z]*$")`  gives:

```
(:SEQUENCE 
 :START-ANCHOR
 (:GREEDY-REPETITION 0
                     NIL
                     (:CHAR-CLASS #\
                                  (:RANGE #\a #\z)
                                  (:RANGE #\A #\Z)))
 :END-ANCHOR)
```

The above form has its uses when you have to combine regular expressions, because it is much easier than concatenating and escaping strings.